# JPA @OneToMany : foreign key is null in db

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, spring-data-jpa

Controller class

```
@PostMapping("employees")
public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> createEmployees(@RequestBody List<Employee> employee) {
    List<Employee> newUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Employee emp : employee){
        Employee newUser = employeeRepository.save(emp);
        newUsers.add(newUser);
    }
```

Employee

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private double salary;

    private String position;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee")
    private List<Address> addresses;
```

Address class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String street;

    private String city;

    private String state;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;
```

Payload :

```
[{
    "name": "test-user433242",
    "salary": "94457020",
    "position": "developer-244332",
        "addresses": [
            {         
               "street": "Ne22w st 444331",
                "city": "Ne22w york city 443321",
               "state": "N22ew york state 43321"
               
             },
             {         
               "street": "texas st 211332",
               "city": "texas city 22332",
               "state": "texas state 23332"   
             }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "test-user2133323",
    "salary": "94777030",
    "position": "developer33-21332",
        "addresses": [
            {         
               "street": "New3 st 211332",
               "city": "New york city 22332",
               "state": "Ne33w york state 23332"   
             },
                         {         
               "street": "buffaol st 211332",
               "city": "buffalo city 22332",
               "state": "buffalo state 23332"   
             }
    ]
}]
```

Here post API is saving all address class fields except the corresponding foreign key(employee_id) in the address class when I try to create a new employee, it saves it as null in DB.

When you save an Employee object that has a collection of Address objects, JPA should cascade the save operation to the associated Address objects automatically if you've properly configured the cascade settings.

How do I save the employee data with the corresponding address?

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the `Address` object know of its `Employee` object and vise versa. So before you save the `newUser` just set the `Employee` of the `Address`

```
for(Employee emp : employees){
    // Set the employee reference in each address
    if (emp.getAddresses() != null) {
        for (Address address : emp.getAddresses()) {
            address.setEmployee(emp);
        }
    }
    Employee newUser = employeeRepository.save(emp);
    newUsers.add(newUser);
}
```

Comment: while sending json everything is mapped by default excepts the id's of employee and the address

Comment: Mustafa is correct. For this example in github with before and after tests see: https://github.com/timurcelikel/stack-overflow-questions/blob/main/src/test/java/com/stackoverflow/questions/q77427608/EmployeeControllerTest.java

Comment: When you save an Employee object that has a collection of Address objects, JPA should cascade the save operation to the associated Address objects automatically if you've properly configured the cascade settings. isn't it?